# How to import SNMP walks into mimicview gambit as agents?

Tags: snmp

I am fairly new to the program being used which is MimicView Gambit. From what I know it mimics a node/switch/router to simulate real time activity.

What I need to do is using a SNMP walk results to somehow import the .wlk file into mimicview as an agent. An agent is referred to as the node/switch/router.

Does anyone have any information on how to approach this or some leads/documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question. The quickest answer will come from `support@gambitcomm.com`.

The simplest way to create a simulation is to record the device directly,
for example, see this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-KctvDus7KU).

If you have a walkfile, you can use Simulation->Record File in MIMICView.

There are many more ways to import devices into the [SNMP Simulator](http://www.gambitcomm.com)
as documented in the online documentation.

Comment: Please note if you want to promote your own product/blog you **must disclose your affiliation**, otherwise your answer may be flagged as spam. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Answer (score 0):

I had never heard before about MimicView, but I'm working on similar project. So fast view via Mimic's FAQ seems to give the [answer](http://www.gambitcomm.com/faq/#walkfile). In short, as far as I understand you have to write file using net-snmp `snmpwalk` command with option `-One`, like

```
snmpwalk -One -v2c -cpublic ip.of.your.device > result.wlk
```

and then fed result to MimicRecorder, eg. in MIMICView use Simulation->Record File. In any case you should read that link and the walkfile converters section in the Utilities Guide for more details.